# pdf 3d with JavaScript : simple example

Tags: javascript, pdf, 3d

I need to do a simple pdf with some 3D objects for an oral presentation. I made several views, each one with a camera viewpoint, an object and a display mode. 
To avoid the need to manually switch between the different viewpoints with the context menu, I would like the viewpoints to switch automatically with a Timer (each viewpoint staying for a few seconds). And I would like to not have to touch the mouse at all (nor the keyboard), so I would like to have the playback started as soon as the page appears.

I found the javascript command runtime.setView(N,x) to switch to the x'th view among N, but I don't know where to put it (I don't want to define a function which will be called when I press a button, since I want everything to be automated). Also, I don't know how to pause for a few seconds.

Any help ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `setInterval(fn, time)` which will call a function periodically at a time interval that you set.  I'm not familiar with the `setView()` method you mentioned, but here's some pseudo code that you would put in  tags at the end of the document body.

```
function startSwitcher()
    var viewNum = 0;
    var maxViews = 5;     // you set this to how many views there are
    setInterval(function()  {
        ++viewNum;
        if (viewNum >= maxViews) {
            viewNum = 0;
        }
        runtime.setView(N, viewNum);     // you will have to figure out this line 
    }, 2000);
}

startSwitcher();
```

The `2000` is 2000 milliseconds and is the time interval between executing the function.  You can put any number of milliseconds there.

The `runtime.setView(N, viewNum)` line is something you will have to figure out as I am not familiar with whatever library you're trying to use there.  The operative part of this code is the `viewNum` variable which configures which view in rotation should be next.

Comment: Thanks - but when I use this code (with N = maxViews), the script doesn't seem to start when the 3D object is displayed. I don't know the behavior of 3d pdfs with javascripts embedded in case of syntax errors or bugs : if there is a syntax error, does the script start and shows an error message ? I am also very new to JS and 3d pdfs. Thanks!

Comment: @WhitAngl - you will have to find out how to communicate with a 3d pdf from webpage javascript.  I would assume you have to use javascript to get the PDF object in the page, register some sort of callback for when it's loaded and then call some methods on it.  But, I don't even know what tools you're using.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm just using Adobe Acrobat Pro, which allows to integrate 3d elements and attach some javascript files... I don't know how to communicate between both, and there seems to be very little documentation and tutorials about it :s

Comment: @WhitAngl - sorry, I can help you with the webpage side of things, but not with communicating with an Acrobat document.

Comment: that's fine :) If I find out by myself the second part of the question, I'll validate your answer :)  (I'm advancing : apparently, the proper method to call is : getAnnots3D(this.pageNum)[0].context3D.runtime.setView(viewNum, true);  but this doesn't change anything)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `runtime.SetView(..)` Methods works with the name of the view as a string instead of the viewnumber. I have this function in a Dokument-level script and it works for me:

```js
// view is the name of the view for example "TopView"
function setView(view){
 console.println("Navigating to view: "+view);
 
 var pageIndex = this.pageNum;

 var annotIndex = 0;

 var c3d = this.getAnnots3D( pageIndex )[ annotIndex ].context3D;

 c3d.runtime.setView(view, true);
}
```

Combine this with the `setInterval(..)` from jfriend00´s answer und you should get what you need.
Best regards